# How to set poster image in JW player from flv file?

Tags: thumbnails, jwplayer, flv, video-thumbnails

How can I set a poster image using particular video frame (flv)?
I don't have image file available, so I wonder if it's possible to set a poster image "in the fly" from the video source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible with JW Player.

Edit: A little more explanation.... JW Player doesn't actually "play" or "process" the video in any way. It's just a steering and styling script - it feeds the video to the browser's `<video>` tag if the browser can handle it, or to the Flash plugin. The player provides its own control bar, advertising capabilities, and so on, but when it comes to the video file itself, the player isn't touching it. So, there's no way to do things like extracting certain frames. The player isn't ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little bit of a hack you can use:

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
  jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
    autostart: true,
    mute: true,
    controls: false
  });
</script>

<script>
  setTimeout(function() { 
    jwplayer().pause();
    jwplayer().setMute(false);
    jwplayer().setControls(true);
  },3000);
</script>
```

What this does is basically autostarts the player, muted, with no controls, then after a second, pauses the player, and sets the controls and volume back. Essentially it is grabbing the first frame. Keep in mind this is a bit of a hack and isn't great for bandwidth.

Comment: And given the number of videos that start (and end) with a second or two of black screen, it may not yield a visible image, anyway. Won't work on a mobile device, either, since there's no autostart possible there.

Comment: Yeah, this is why I mentioned that this is a hack, really.